# Update ignore unique constraint key if the value is already on the table. - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have this oracle command.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NUMBERS
SET mdn = concat(concat(substr(mdn,1,2),`9`,substr(mdn,3,9))
WHERE mdn LIKE `8%` AND LENGTH(mdn)=10;
```

I have to put the number 9 on the 3 position if the number start with 8 and have 10 digits.

Let's suppose I have `8187412868`, it will be `81987412868`.

But `81987412868` and `8187412868` is already on the table.

In this case there is no need to update or remove, but i would like to ignore the unique constraint error to execute the whole query.

like

```
    if (concat(concat(subsrtr(mdn,1,2),`9`,substr(mdn,3,9))
    WHERE mdn LIKE `8%` AND LENGHT(mdn)=10)
    already on the table, then ignore
    else
    execute....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `exists` operator to pre-check if this value exits (also, note I fixes the brackets and typos in the OP's query):

```
UPDATE table_numbers a
SET    mdn = CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(mdn, 1, 2), '9') ,SUBSTR(mdn, 3, 9))
WHERE  mdn LIKE '8%' AND 
       LENGTH(mdn) = 10 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table_numbers b
                   WHERE  a.mdn = CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(b.mdn, 1, 2), 
                                                '9'), 
                                         SUBSTR(b.mdn, 3, 9))
```

Comment: Thx for edit. Fist time here. Yours sql is missing 1 ")", but even with that i got the same msg. "unique constraint viol'ated"